# Injecting a global variable before page load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've [this page](https://www.irctc.co.in)  and in my background page I'm blocking  a url which defines `stationName` variable.

As explained in
[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) I'm able to inject `stationName` variable( using first technique) but unfortunately it gets injected too late, after execution of all downloaded javascript code from website which don't find `stationName` variable.

How to define this variable before the javascript execution of page starts?

Comment: How is your content script invoked? With an entry in the manifest or programmatically? Did you use the `run_at: document_start` option?

Comment: @rsanchez the content script is declared in the manifest. I've not used run_at

Answer (score 0):

I've placed this file at `resources/irctc` containing `stationName` variable and in `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`  I'm redirecting it :

```
return   {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL('resources/irctc/stationnames.js')
};
```

And it's working but I'm still looking for the right way.